# Контекстное меню в Android

Tags: java, android, listview, меню, popupmenu

Доброго всем времени суток!

У меня есть ListView, и я хочу к каждому его элементу прикрутить контекстное меню. Часто видел в приложениях, что контекстное меню для элементов листвью вызывается при клике на специальную кнопку с тремя квадратами. Не знаю, как называется эта кнопка, поэтому даже не могу нормально погуглить. Выглядит эта кнопка так:

[image]

Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за кнопка и как наилучшим образом приделать контекстное меню к каждому элементу listview? Спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Кнопка называется "`overflow`". Скачать её можно в интернете, на `habre` был когда-то пост со ссылкой на пак с разноцветными иконками.
2. Меню называется "`PopUpMenu`". Чтобы его вызвать нужно:

   1) Добавить в лэйаут элемента списка саму иконку, найти её в адаптере и далее:

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
       //popUp menu        
       holderMain.settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
           popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
               public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                   switch (item.getItemId()) {
                       case R.id.mark_as_read:
                       //действие
                       return true;
                       case R.id.share_link:
                      //действие
                       return true;
                       case R.id.show_comments:
                       //действие
                       return true;
                       default:
                       return false;
                   }
               }
           });
       MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
       popup.show();
       }
   });
   ```

   2) Ну и ещё нужен popup_menu.xml в папке /res/menu

   ```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
       android:id="@+id/mark_as_read"
       android:orderInCategory="10"
       android:title="@string/mark_as_read"/>
   <item
       android:id="@+id/share_link"
       android:orderInCategory="50"
       android:title="@string/share_link"/>
   <item
       android:id="@+id/show_comments"
       android:orderInCategory="100"
       android:title="@string/show_comments"/>
   </menu>
   ```

Comment: Ну что за беда с форматированием... =(

Comment: @Expert, 

    try
    {
    summonModeratorForTextFromatting.help();
    }
    catch(LazyModeratorException laaazy)
    {
    laaazy.helpMePlease(cookies);
    }
    finally
    {
    tryToDoItMyself(noNoNO, iCanT(doThis));
    }

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо!

Comment: @JuniorTwo, пожалуйста)

Сам пару недель назад всё это в доках нагуглил, зная только название кнопки.

Comment: А вот еще [проблемка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/430888/177345) есть, с этим связанная. Как то решали или игнорируете?

Comment: @pavlofff, в первый раз о таком слышу))) Буду дома - потестирую у себя, отпишусь. А так получается да - игнорирую) Мне кажется интуитивно ожидаемым НЕвосстановление этого меню при повороте экрана. И у меня мысль - вы в классе-холдере логику реализуете. По мне так это неверный подход. В холдере должны быть только члены класса определены, а всю логику выносить в `onBindViewHolder` или как-там замена `getView` называется

Comment: Да дело не в ожиданиях, а в исключении, если при повороте меню открыто - на это не влияет где оно вызвано, в холдере или в адаптере. Проблема связана с потерей хост-активити при перерисовке меню. С точки зрения архитектурного решения нет разницы, где вешать слушатели - в холдере или адаптере, просто, если вынести в холдер, то визуально разгружается код адаптера, а так оба подхода одинаково практикуются.

Comment: @pavlofff, пара часов лютого гугленья и я таки решил задачу) И она таки решается гораздо проще, если меню из адаптера вызывается. Но я пофиксил сей баг и при вызове `PopupMenu` из холдера (как у вас в вопросе). В течении часа вам в вопросе отвечу. С вас плюсики)