# PopupMenu выбрасывает WindowLeaked при повороте устройства

Tags: java, android, popupmenu, recyclerview

Реализую overflow-кнопку для элемента списка, кнопка обрабатывается в холдере адаптера:

```
class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <CustomAdapter.ItemHolder> {

....

 public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        ImageButton mMenuItem;
        CardView mCard;

        public ItemHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            mCard = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card);
            mMenuItem = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.menu_button);

            mMenuItem.setOnClickListener(this);
            mCard.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.menu_button:
                        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mMenuItem.getContext(), mMenuItem);
                        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
                        popupMenu.show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.card:
                        //
                        break;
            }
       }
  }
 }
```

Если меню раскрыто, то при повороте устройства получаю исключение:

> E WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.android.test.MyActivity

Понятно, что менюшка теряет прошлую активити при пересоздании и, в общем то, это не приводит к падению приложения и вообще никак не проявляется, если не смотреть logcat, но хотелось бы решить проблему.
Собственно решение, как таковое, известно - закрывать `PopupMenu` в методах закрытия активити, например `onPause()` - `popupmenu.dissmis()`. Проблема в том, что это меню создается в адаптере и ему о жизненном цикле активити ничего не известно. Можно, конечно, уведомить адаптер, что вызван метод `onPause()` и закрыть эту менюшку, но получается все довольно коряво - нужно переносить инициализацию меню в сам адаптер и тп. нежелательные решения.

Посмотрел большое количество примеров реализации, в том числе эталонный [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/b3c3ae2a5b41e28c07383644d78e5c076288322f/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/PeopleIveMetFragment.java#L494), везде эта проблема просто игнорируется, даже гуглом.

Вопрос такой:  как решить и стоит ли вообще обращать внимание на эту проблему или какие то альтернативные способы реализации меню в айтеме для `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку вложенный в адаптер класс `ItemHolder` статический, то для решения проблемы сделал следующее:

1. Объявил `PopupMenu` статическим полем класса - теперь все экземпляры меню будут "связаны", как будто это один экземпляр:

   ```
   public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    ImageButton mMenuItem;
    CardView mCard;
    public static PopupMenu popupMenu;
    ...

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     ...
       if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
           switch (v.getId()) {
               case R.id.menu_button:
                   popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mMenuItem.getContext(), mMenuItem);
                   ...
       }
    }
   }
   ```
2. В `onPause()` активити, в которую выводится список, обращаюсь напрямую к этому статическому экземпляру через класс адаптера с предложением закрыться:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();

     PopupMenu popupMenu = CustomAdapter.ItemHolder.popupMenu;
     if (popupMenu != null) popupMenu.dismiss();
     popupMenu = null; // защита от утечек памяти
   }
   ```

При желании можно написать геттер, чтобы отдавал `PopupMenu`. В данном случае я не вижу в этом особой надобности.

PS: По прежнему хотел бы услышать более оптимальное решение.

Comment: Изящно) Я в этом плохо разбираюсь, но разве пользование статических членов в классе не будет приводить ко всяким утечкам памяти, в отличие от моего, пусть и менее изящного варианта?

Comment: К тому же, как я упоминал, если вызывать меню из адаптера, и сделать меню обычным членом адаптера, то выглядеть всё это будет так: `((MyAdapter)recycler.getAdapter()).popupMenu.dismiss();` - и никакой статики.

Comment: Если совсем не охота в `onBindViewHolder()` что-то писать, то можно класс холдера определить внутри адаптера - доступ к члену адаптера будет.

Comment: Насчет утечки это вы верно подметили, лучше перестраховаться - немного исправил. Холдер и так внутрений класс адаптера, просто это не явно видно из кода - исправил тоже.

Answer (score 2):

Для решения проблемы нам надо:

1. В нужный момент (при "смерти" активити) закрыть `PopupMenu`.
2. А для этого надо получить ссылку на объект `PopupMenu`.
3. А оно определено в `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.
4. Значит нам надо получить ссылку на `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`
5. И в нём-то и будет искомое `PopupMenu`.

Добавим поле в холдер для хранения меню, а также геттер:

```
public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{

    ImageButton mMenuItem;
    CardView mCard;
    //сюда будем ссылку на меню сохранять
    PopupMenu popup;
    //так будем его из холдера получать
    public PopupMenu getPopup()
    {
        return popup;
    }

    public ItemHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        mCard = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card);
        mMenuItem = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.menu_button);

        //устанавливаем тэг одному из элементов разметки
        //чтобы потом вызовом View.getTag() получить ссылку на экземпляр холдера
        mMenuItem.setTag(this);

        mMenuItem.setOnClickListener(this);
        mCard.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.menu_button:
                    //инициализируем поле класса
                    popup = new PopupMenu(mMenuItem.getContext(), mMenuItem);

                    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
                    popupMenu.show();
                    break;
                case R.id.card:
                    //
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Все инструменты готовы, теперь можно в методах жизненного цикла `Activity` или `Fragment`, используя лишь ссылку на `RecyclerView`, находить `PopupMenu` в элементах списка и вызывать над ними `PopupMenu.dismiss()`, что устранит вываливание в логи сообщения об ошибке:

```
    //можно оптимизировать, но для простоты пробежимся по всем элементам
    for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View recyclerViewElement = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(i);
        if (recyclerViewElement == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        //находим в элементе View, хранящую ссылку на холдер
        View viewThatHoldsReferenceToHolder = recyclerViewElement.findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
        if (viewThatHoldsReferenceToHolder == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        //получаем ссылку на холдер
        ItemHolder holder = ((ItemHolder) viewThatHoldsReferenceToHolder .getTag());
        if (holder != null)
        {
            //Вот оно - наше меню!
            PopupMenu popup = holder.getPopup();
            if (popup != null)
            {
                //Закрываем его и задачу на правку бага
                popup.dismiss();
                Log.d(LOG, "Красота, а не ругань системы в логах! =)");
            }
        }
    }
```

В случае же вызывания `PopupMenu` из адаптера всё гораздо проще - получаем ссылку на меню из адаптера и... Всё, вопрос решён. Буду считать сей случай доводом в пользу писания всей логики обработки элемента списка в адаптере, а не в классе холдера.

Comment: Спасибо , проголосовал за желание помочь, но это слишком сложное решение. [Сделал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462239/177345) намного проще.