# RecyclerView: проблема при обработке клика на Item

Tags: android, adapter, recyclerview

В приложении использую RecyclerView, в котором определяю 2 VIEW TYPES, соответственно во фрагменте создаю для каждого вида свой обработчик, который передаю в адаптер. Обработчик нажатия ITEM'ов ведет себя адекватно, а обработчик нажатия FOOTER'а получает ивент очень непостоянно, при массовом нажатии ивент проскакивает на 10-12 раз порцией в 3-4 ивента, а потом опять в листенер ничего не поступает.

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener{
private Logger logger = Logger.createLogger(null);
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 1;
private List<Message> messages;
private View.OnClickListener footerOnClickListener;
private MainFragment.OnMessageSelectListener onMessageSelectListener;


public MessagesAdapter(Context context) {
    this.messages = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setFooterOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener footerOnClickListener) {
    this.footerOnClickListener = footerOnClickListener;
}

public void setOnMessageSelectListener(MainFragment.OnMessageSelectListener onMessageSelectListener) {
    this.onMessageSelectListener = onMessageSelectListener;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int layoutResId = (TYPE_ITEM == viewType) ? R.layout.message_item_layout : R.layout.footer_message_list_layout;
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layoutResId, parent, false);
return (TYPE_ITEM == viewType) ? new MessageItemHolder(view) : new FooterHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder instanceof MessageItemHolder) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);

        MessageItemHolder messageHolder = (MessageItemHolder) holder;
        messageHolder.messageContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
        messageHolder.messageContainer.setTag(messageHolder);
        //TODO

    } else {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logger.info("MessagesAdapter: onClick: ");
            }
        });

    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messages.isEmpty() ? 0 : messages.size() + 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == messages.size()) ? TYPE_FOOTER : TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    MessageItemHolder holder = (MessageItemHolder) view.getTag();
    int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    onMessageSelectListener.onMessageSelected(messages.get(position));
}

class MessageItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.messageTitle) TextView title;
    @Bind(R.id.messageDescription) TextView paragraph;
    @Bind(R.id.messageIcon) ImageView icon;
    @Bind(R.id.message_layout) RelativeLayout messageContainer;
    private Context context;

    public MessageItemHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

class FooterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.footer_layout) LinearLayout footer;
    public FooterHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    style="@style/Fill.WithBaseBackground">
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/message_list_separator"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingTop="32dp"
    android:paddingBottom="24dp"
    android:textColor="@color/bottom_text_color_selector"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="@string/footer_label"/>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в колбек ивент приходит очень непостоянно, возможно этот ивент где-то перехватывается. Подскажите. в каком направлении искать

Comment: Стандартной и рекомендованной практикой является посадка слушателя внутри `ViewHolder` - я вижу вашу проблему именно в этом, вернее отсутствии этого в вашем коде. Вы вешаете слушатель в момент связывания `ViewHolder`, что очевидно и является причиной проблемы.

Comment: @Barmaley, а где именно так рекомендуется поступать? Уже второй раз об этом слышу, но сам лично в `onBindViewHolder` всё что можно вешаю и проблем не имею... Зато знаю один случай, когда вешание слушателей в самом холдере оборачивается ненужными проблемами... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461808/17609

Comment: Я и сам не помню - просто столько много всякой инфы постоянно рядом вращается, не успеваешь следить за причинно-следственной связью. Иногда проще забить и сказать себе: вот так вот правильно (паттерн) и вперед (на то он и паттерн, то есть некто уже успел набить шишки за тебя). В приведенном примере неверно использован паттерн: в холдере создается аж целый виджет! А надо то ведь по другому: в холдере надо вызывать метод слушателя (как в примере @georgehardcode) и так уже в том методе что-то делать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я реализовывал похожий адаптер, клики реализованы внутри ViewHolder, все нормально работает, чуть-чуть поправил Ваш код:

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private Logger logger = Logger.createLogger(null);
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 1;
    private List<Message> messages;
    private MessageClickListener itemClickListener;


    public MessagesAdapter(Context context) {
        this.messages = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(MessageClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        int layoutResId = (TYPE_ITEM == viewType) ? R.layout.message_item_layout : R.layout.footer_message_list_layout;
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layoutResId, parent, false);
        return (TYPE_ITEM == viewType) ? new MessageItemHolder(view) : new FooterHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof MessageItemHolder) {
            Message message = messages.get(position);
            MessageItemHolder messageHolder = (MessageItemHolder) holder;
            messageHolder.messageContainer.setTag(messageHolder);
            //TODO
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.isEmpty() ? 0 : messages.size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == messages.size()) ? TYPE_FOOTER : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    class MessageItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Bind(R.id.messageTitle) TextView title;
        @Bind(R.id.messageDescription) TextView paragraph;
        @Bind(R.id.messageIcon) ImageView icon;
        @Bind(R.id.message_layout) RelativeLayout messageContainer;
        private Context context;

        public MessageItemHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemClickListener.onMessageClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    class FooterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Bind(R.id.footer_layout)
        LinearLayout footer;

        public FooterHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemClickListener.onFooterClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Интерфейс: для вывода в контекст:

```
public interface MessageClickListener {

    void onMessageClick(View view, int position);

    void onFooterClick(View view, int position);
}
```

P.S. и еще уберите из `LinearLayout`

```
     android:clickable="true"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

и  `android:clickable="true"` из `TextView`

Comment: спасибо за рефакторинг, но это не помогло, там проблема где-то на уровне прохождени/я ивента в листенер, вроде все правильно, но событие в лисенер не попадает

Comment: @AlexZiko уберите атрибуты из xml, которые я указал

Comment: да, проблема оказалась в xml, спасибо

Comment: @AlexZiko, да не за что