# Логика приложения Андроид (RecyclerView)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, recyclerview

Здравствуйте. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться со следующим.

Есть БД, данные из БД выводятся на `CardView`ы, которые в свою очередь генерятся в зависимости от кол-ва записей в БД.

На этих карточках выведены данные полученные из полей БД. И на этих же карточках присутствует кнопка для удаления записи из БД (нажатие кнопки на карточке удаляет эту карточку и ту строку, которая послужила источником данных для этой карточки).

Суть в том, что я не понимаю, как реализовать эти кнопки...

Скриншот для наглядности:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, теперь к моей реализации:

Для создания объекта **Exercise** я создал следующий класс:

```
package dailytoys.exreminder.DataClasses;


public class Exercise {

    public String name;
    public String muscleGroup;
    public int repeats;
    public int ID;

    public Exercise(String name, String muscleGroup, int repeats, int ID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.muscleGroup = muscleGroup;
        this.repeats = repeats;
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

Вот DBHelper:

```
package dailytoys.exreminder.DataBaseEx;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String name;

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "exeDB", null, 1);
    }

    public int getRowsQuantity (String table) throws SQLException {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int cnt = cursor.getCount();
        return cnt;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        System.out.println("-------- CREATING TABLES ----------");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE EXERCISES (" +
                "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "NAME TEXT," +
                "REPEATS INTEGER," +
                "MUSCLE_GROUP TEXT" + ");");

        ...

    }

    ...

}
```

Собственно, вот Активити, которое отображает карточки:

```
package dailytoys.exreminder;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import dailytoys.exreminder.DataBaseEx.DBHelper;
import dailytoys.exreminder.DataClasses.Exercise;
import dailytoys.exreminder.Dialogs.DialogNewExercise;


public class ExercisesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    /* Данные для добавления на карточки */
    private List<Exercise> exercises;

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    RecyclerAdapter adapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercises);
        ...

        /* Инициализация БД помощника для построения карточек */
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        /* Генерация карточек */
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();
...
    }

    private void initializeData () {

        int rows = dbHelper.getRowsQuantity("EXERCISES");
        exercises = new ArrayList<>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("EXERCISES", null, null, null, null, null, null);

        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("ID");
        int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("NAME");
        int repeatsColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("REPEATS");
        int muscleGroupColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("MUSCLE_GROUP");


        // Цикл для чтения таблицы БД и записи данных в переменные
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
            // Дефолтные значения переменных
            String name = null, muscleGroup = null;
            int repeats = 0; int ID = 0;

            // Получение значений из БД
            if (c.moveToNext()) {
                name = c.getString(nameColIndex);
                muscleGroup = c.getString(muscleGroupColIndex);
                repeats = c.getInt(repeatsColIndex);
                ID = c.getInt(idColIndex);

                // добавление в List
                exercises.add(new Exercise(name, muscleGroup, repeats, ID));

            } else {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeAdapter(){
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter((ArrayList)exercises);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void reloadActivity() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    ...


}
```

Карточки генерятся через класс, расширяемый от RecyclerView.Adapter :

```
package dailytoys.exreminder;


import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import dailytoys.exreminder.DataClasses.Exercise;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ExerciseViewHolder> {

    private List<Exercise> exercises;
    ExerciseViewHolder vh;
    public ImageView mDeleteBtn;

    public class ExerciseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView, mTextViewName, mTextViewMusckeGroup, mTextViewRepeats;

        public ExerciseViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item);
            mTextViewName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.exerciseNameEx);
            mTextViewMusckeGroup = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvMuscleGroup);
            mTextViewRepeats = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvRepeats);
            mDeleteBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtnEx);
        }

    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Exercise> exercises) {
        this.exercises = exercises;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ExerciseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        vh = new ExerciseViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExerciseViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText("ID: " + Integer.toString(exercises.get(position).ID));
        holder.mTextViewName.setText(exercises.get(position).name);
        holder.mTextViewMusckeGroup.setText(exercises.get(position).muscleGroup);
        holder.mTextViewRepeats.setText(Integer.toString(exercises.get(position).repeats));
        mDeleteBtn.setTag(exercises.get(position).ID);

    }

    public ImageView getImgView () {
        return mDeleteBtn;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return exercises.size();
    }

}
```

Ну, и на всякий случай, оставлю разметки карточки, и RecyclerView.

activity_exercises.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="dailytoys.exreminder.ExercisesActivity"
    android:id="@+id/parentViewExercisesActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:clickable="false" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_exercises" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabExercises"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        android:background="#d10000"
        app:backgroundTint="#2f00ff" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_exercises.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

recycler_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:imageView="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="34dp"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/exercises_black"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_recycler_item"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="10dp"
                    android:text="#1"
                    android:textColor="#abaab1" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Exercise Name"
                    android:id="@+id/exerciseNameEx" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Repeats:"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Small Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvRepeats"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Muscle group:"
                        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Small Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvMuscleGroup"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/deleteBtnEx"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/delete" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Ну, и, собственно, для того, чтобы по клику на кнопку "удалить" (та которая `ImageView` с изображением корзины) происходило удаление записи по её ID, я решил сетить ей ID. То есть, вот так:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExerciseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    mDeleteBtn.setTag(exercises.get(position).ID);
}
```

Но проблема в том, что абсолютно всем экземплярам кнопке (на всех карточках) сетится один и тот же ID (последняя запись в таблице).

И вопрос в том, как же мне сделать так, чтобы на каждой кнопке висел тег с правильной айдишкой (которая соответствует информации на карточке).

Comment: Код выделяется как блок отступом в 4 пробела на каждой строке. Для такого форматирования, сначала вставьте ваш код, затем выделите его целиком, и затем нажмите кнопку `{}`. Скрипт либо добавит 4 пробела к каждой выделенной строке, либо удалит, если они все начинались с 4 пробелов.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Ни в коем случае не приследовал цели показать неуважение к пользователям ресурса. Лишнее в коде убрал. А на счёт форматирования, то я просто неверно понял, как вставлять код. Возьму на заметку, спасибо.

Comment: Человек написал аккуратно структуру БД, наверстал норм карточку, сделал отдельный класс с конструктором Exercise  для более удобного управления данными, практически всё правильно расставил в адаптере, правильная аккуратная структура ViewHolder. И он на кнопку не может повесить onClick где будет удалятся элемент из List? не верю

Comment: Можете не верить. Видимо, нужно было уточнить, что ООП, ровно как и Android я только изучаю, и конкретно эта задача для меня очень сложная. Делал это по гайду. На счёт класса Exercise - не вижу ничего сложного, это писалось собственноручно. А вот ViewHolder - это уже по гайду.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public ExerciseViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item);
        mTextViewName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.exerciseNameEx);
        mTextViewMusckeGroup = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvMuscleGroup);
        mTextViewRepeats = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvRepeats);
        mDeleteBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtnEx);
        mDeleteBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        delete(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

....

```
public void delete(int position) {
    exercises.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Можете всё в onClick запихать, но советую так оставить, не нужно грузить listner-ы в адаптере, будет удобней расширять потом.

Comment: @PashaOleynik Хочется добавить, что очень желательно при получении позиции в холдере методом `getAdapterPosition()` делать проверку на `NO_POSITION`, так как такая ситуация может получится и приложение скорее всего упадет. [Для примера](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/430888/177345) реализация метода `onClick()` в моем вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

1. Не надо тэг для этого использовать.
2. У вас mDeleteBtn член класса адаптера и всегда содержит ссылку на последний отрисованный элемент списка.
3. Вам, видимо, хотелось кнопку удаления в разметку каждого элемента добавить. Если так, то получить ID при нажатии на неё вы можете просто по позиции в onBindViewHolder

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Окей, на счёт получения ID смутно, но понял идею. Осталось подумать, как это реализовать. 
На счёт первого пункта - а как вообще нужно подходить к подобным задачам? Почему тэг не подходит?

Comment: @PashaOleynik, Во первых у вас кнопка удалить есть в разметке, но её нет в холдере. А в адаптере она не нужна. Единственное применение тегу коt я знаю - это реализация паттерна ViewHolder в ListView.

Comment: да, я понимаю, что кнопка должна быть в холдере. Но тогда и OnClickListener тоже должен быть там же? Дело в том, что изначально всё так и было, но при попытках вернуть View кнопки в Активити (дабы обработать нажатие), кнопка терялась. Вот этого момента я не понимаю. Но, я увидел, почему так происходило. Проблема была в том, что onCreateViewHolder срабатывал поздно, из-за чего не успевал создать объект кнопки. 
После вызова методов `initializeData()` и `initializeAdaptor()` в `onCreate` активити была инициализация кнопки, `ImageView imgV = adaptor.getmDeleteButton();`

Comment: не могу понять, где мне необходимо обрабатывать клик (сетить OnClickListener)

Comment: @PashaOleynik, назначать слушатель надо в onBindViewHolder. Там у вас как раз позиция есть, необходимая для получения ID. Активити знать об этой кнопке и вовсе не надо.

Comment: Большое спасибо, вот теперь малость прояснилось.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно ошибка в этом методе

```
   @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ExerciseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        vh = new ExerciseViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
```

У вас ViewHolder объявлен  переменной класса

```
 private List<Exercise> exercises;
 ExerciseViewHolder vh;
 public ImageView mDeleteBtn;э
```

Попробуйте сделать так

```
   @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ExerciseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        ExerciseViewHolder vh = new ExerciseViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
```

И удалить строку   `ExerciseViewHolder vh;` в начале класса