# RecyclerView некорректно отображается

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

RecyclerView соответствует должному размеру, но между итемами пробелы. Как это выглядит:
RecyclerView с 4 итемами,
где ***--*** - пустое место

1 итем

**--**

**--**

**--**

2 итем

**--**

**--**

......

4 итем

**--**

**--**

**--**

Layout итема для recyclerview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="1dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_blue"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_name"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Хлеб"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_quantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/product_name"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/product_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_name"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/product_mesurement"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bottle_48px"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_name"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/product_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="26.95"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/product_mesurement"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="₽"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/product_price"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout с RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/productsInBasket"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
            android:id="@+id/payButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#00C853"
            android:text="Оплачено: 4700₽"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/payButton"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_shopping"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.kh.smartlist.utils.ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Проблема появилась после обновления 23.2. При этом при последнем обновлении 23.2.1 проблема не решилась.

Comment: С выходом 23.3 проблема тоже не решилась

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Попробуйте так:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="1dp">
```

Comment: А вообще, неплохо бы просто хорошенько присмотреться к вашим View в визуальном редакторе. Там сразу будет видно, в чем проблема.

Comment: У моих view в визуальном редакторе нет проблем. К сожалению, ваше решение не помогло

Comment: Возможно, Вам поможет это: http://pastebin.com/ULhHGjcS
В этом примере карточки генерируются без "пустого места".
Ещё можете посмотреть этот вопрос [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505667/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4-recyclerview).

Answer (score 0):

Это проблема одной из версий библиотек поддержки от гугла. А именно в значении высоты корневого элемента разметки списка.

Должно сработать или

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

или

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: Попробовал разные варианты, не помогает

Comment: @АнтонХоркин, а если самому `RecyclerView` проставить высоту `android:layout_height="match_parent"` вместо `wrap_content`?..

Comment: Тоже не работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте у RelativeLayout поставить высоту wrap_content

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
```

Comment: Пробовал разные варианты с wrap_content и match_parent, все равно не отображается, как надо. Ваш вариант тоже не работает.

Comment: @АнтонХоркин может ты используешь какой-то Decorator который эти отступы задает?

Comment: не знаю, что такое decorator