# ContextMenu в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, menu

Хочу добавить ContextMenu в RecyclerView, имплементирую View.OnCreateContextMenuListener во ViewHolder и переопределяю метод onCreateContextMenu, но  ContextMenu не появляется. Что я неправильно делаю?

```
 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
        private TextView titleMain;
        private TextView numbSlides;
        private TextView title;
        private TextView date;
        private ImageView image1;
        private ImageView image2;
        private ImageView image3;
        private ImageView image4;
        private ImageView image5;
        private TextView slides;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            titleMain = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_main);
            numbSlides = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.number);
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
            slides = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
            image1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon1);
            image2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon2);
            image3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon3);
            image4 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon4);
            image5 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon5);
            v.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

            menu.setHeaderTitle("Select");
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Share");
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте это не в холдере делать, а в адаптере, в `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Я делал [обычный PopupMenu](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/430888/177345). В референсном приложении-примере от Google IOSched реализована такая же схема. Если нужна не отдельная кнопка, а длинный клик, то вешаем открытие попапа на `OnLongClickListener` по всему айтему