# RecyclerView, обработчик нажатия на кнопку в айтеме CardView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, cardview

Использую список RecyclerView,  пункты состоят из  cardview, в каждом из которых есть текст и кнопка. 
С обработчиком нажатия на сам пункт вроде все понятно

```
    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Context context = v.getContext();
        Intent ddddd = new Intent(context, LastActivity.class);
        long yy = personsFitr.get(getAdapterPosition()).id;
        String str = Long.toString(yy);
        ddddd.putExtra("id", str);
        context.startActivity(ddddd);

    }
}
```

А как обработать именно нажатия на кнопку в item?

---

Более подробна

Создал модель данных

Person

```
public class Person {
long id;
String title;
String prich;
String affirm;
String favorite;
int photoId;
```

Заполняю модель данных из БД (использую Sugar ORM)

```
// заполнил модель данных
persons = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Contact contact:allContacts){
        persons.add(new Person(contact.getId(), contact.title, contact.prich, contact.affirm, contact.favorite, contact.photoId));
    }
```

В адаптаре все это получаю.
До этого в приложении, при нажатии на пункт, переходил во второе Активити куда передовал id, во втором Активити получал id, и по id выводил уже данные из БД.

Так же во втором Активити была кнопка, при нажатии на которое пункт добавлялся в Избранное.

Но это не очень красиво правельней было бы добавлять в избранное, с  самого пункта в списке, к примеру если нажать на кнопку.

Код адаптара

```
public class CheeseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheeseAdapter.Holder> {
public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cv;
    TextView title;
    TextView title2;
    ImageView personPhoto;
    Button button;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cheeseName);
        title2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        personPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo22);
        button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = v.getContext();
        Intent ddddd = new Intent(context, LastActivity.class);
        long yy = personsFitr.get(getAdapterPosition()).id;
        String str2 = Long.toString(yy);
        ddddd.putExtra("id", str2);
        context.startActivity(ddddd);
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), personsFitr.get(getAdapterPosition()).title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
List<Person> persons;
List<Person> personsFitr;

//
public CheeseAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, List<Person> persons11) {
    mInflater = inflater;
    persons = persons11;
    personsFitr=persons;
}
@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new Holder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
    View itemView = holder.itemView;


    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //нужный код
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "текст", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    holder.title.setText(personsFitr.get(position).title);
    holder.title2.setText(personsFitr.get(position).prich);
    holder.personPhoto.setImageResource(personsFitr.get(position).photoId);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return personsFitr.size();
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно вынести получение ссылок на элементы айтема из адаптера в холдер (иначе смысл холдера вовсе теряется) и в холдере повесить на них обработчики. Смотрите холдер [в этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/430888/177345) - здесь клик на весь айтем и отдельно на кнопку, которая выводит попап.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую разобраться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

Поле favorite должно быть типа `boolean`, а не `String`

```
public class CheeseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheeseAdapter.Holder> {

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cv;
    TextView title;
    TextView title2;
    ImageView personPhoto;
    Button button;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cheeseName);
        title2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        personPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo22);
        button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    }
}

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
List<Person> persons;
List<Person> personsFitr;

public CheeseAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, List<Person> persons11) {
    mInflater = inflater;
    persons = persons11;
    personsFitr=persons;
}
@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new Holder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(personsFitr.get(position).title);
    holder.title2.setText(personsFitr.get(position).prich);
    holder.personPhoto.setImageResource(personsFitr.get(position).photoId);

    // окрашиваем кнопку для выделения, что  элемент в избранном

    if (personsFitr.get(position).favorite == false) {
                holder.button.setBackgroundColor(#FFAAAA); //цвет не в избраном
            } else {
                holder.button.setBackgroundColor(#AAAAAA); // цвет в избранном
            }
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

          Context context = v.getContext();
          long id = personsFitr.get(position).id;

          // при нажатии инвертируем добавление в избранное,
          // каждое нажатие добавляет\убирает из избранного

          personsFitr.get(position).favorite = !personsFitr.get(position).favorite;

          // Здесь делаем запись в БД о избранном, значения  элемента с ID = id
          // Записываем в БД в позицию id значение personsFitr.get(position).favorite

          // обновляем элемент в списке, чтобы отобразить новое состояние

          notifyItemChanged(position);
      }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return personsFitr.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например для `title`:

В `onBindViewHolder()`

```
 holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //нужный код
    }
});
```

И так для каждого поля. Смысл в том, что холдер держит ссылки на каждый item, и обращение к ним ничем не отличается, как если бы обрабатывали в обычном классе.

Comment: В вопросе в холдере не хранятся ссылки на элементы айтема, они получаются в самом адаптере, что не правильно и из-за этого нельзя повесить на них обработчики в холдере.

Comment: Не совсем понял, как в холдере сохранить ссылки на элементы айтема??