# Нежелательное поведение элементов RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, api, recyclerview

Всем доброго времени суток! Имеется `RecyclerView`, элементы которого могут выходить за пределы экрана. Каждый элемент представляет из себя `View` с корневым элементом `RelativeLayout`. Все элементы (включая дочерние) в каждом `View` имеют параметр высоты `wrap_content`. Каждый `View` зарегистрирован в `Activity` для отображения контекстного меню методом `Activity.registerForContextMenu()`. Сам `RecyclerView` имеет по высоте параметр `match_parent`.

Так вот, вся эта нехитрая связка работает хорошо, пока не вызывается контекстное меню для элемента списка `RecyclerView`. При этом, если элемент больше высоты, отведенной под `RecyclerView`, он насильно масштабируется таким образом, чтобы вписываться в экран. (В TextView обрезается текст, ImageView уменьшает размер картинки)

До вызова контекстного меню:

[image: До вызова <code>ContextMenu</code>]

После вызова:

[image: После вызова <code>ContextMenu</code>]

Я очень долго пытался разобраться с этой проблемой, но так и не понял, из-за чего проявляется такое поведение у элементов списка. Как можно справиться с этой проблемой? Неужели, это баг в Android API?

Comment: В RecyclerView принято делать контекстное меню через PopupMenu. [Пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/430888/177345)

Comment: Переделал с использованием Popup Menu, в таком случае обрезается Popup Menu, оно отображается в одну строчку вверху экрана

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо pavlofff за комментарий, PopupMenu действительно для моих целей подходит лучше, даже несмотря на то, что оно отображается в одну строчку (если места не хватает). Элементы RecyclerView при этом не масштабируются (как и нужно)