# Как удалить Table Row через контекстное меню?

Tags: java, android, android-context-menu

Создал контекстное меню, но оно никак не видит мои Table Row, созданные выше. findViewById не получается сделать, т.к. они создаются программно, без XML файла. Подскажите, как реализовать получение текста из TextView в контекстном меню по нажатому row и его удаление
Есть БД, из которой берутся данные и программно создаются Table Row`s

```
            int nameColumn= tableCursor.getColumnIndex("someColumn");
            String reserveName = tableCursor.getString(nameSome);

            final TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
           TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);



            registerForContextMenu(tl);


            tl.setStretchAllColumns(true);
            tl.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
            tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



            TextView textview = new TextView(this);
            textview.setText(reserveName);
            textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textview.setTextSize(20);
            textview.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            tr.addView(textview);
```

И есть контекстное меню, которое работает и выводит лог при долгом нажатии:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.mainLayout) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Delete row?");

        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Yes");

    }
}
```

**UPDATED**
Смог реализовать получение String из TextView, но проблема в том, что по нажатию на любую row, всегда возвращается значение из  первой row. Подскажите как пофиксить это

```
   @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == 0) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "О БОЖЕ ОНО РАБОТАЕТ");

       // db.delete("mytable", "id = " + id, null);

        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        TableRow row1 = (TableRow)tl.getChildAt(0);

        TextView firstTextView = (TextView) row1.getChildAt(0);
        String firstText = firstTextView.getText().toString();


        Log.d(LOG_TAG, firstText);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

**UPADATE**
В методах типа `onClick(View v)` нажатый элемент определятся по входящему `v`, а как определить какой был нажат элемент в Context Menu? Или я размышляю в неправильном направлении?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Контекстное меню в Android](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/373103/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%b2-android)

Comment: Я откорректировал вопрос. Предложенный Вами выше ответ не подходит. Там другой вопрос.

Comment: `проблема в том, что по нажатию на любую row, всегда возвращается значение из первой row` - естественно, вы же всегда и спрашиваете у первого row - `TableRow row1 = (TableRow)tl.getChildAt(0);`

Comment: @metalurgus И что вы посоветуете, чтобы решить эту проблему? я пробовал присваивать к каждой row свой id, но опять же, как определить что нажата, допустим 4ая row, а не 3ья?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот рабочий код, если кому-то понадобиться.

```
tr.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(final View v)
                {

                    TableRow t = (TableRow) v;
                    TextView firstTextView = (TextView) t.getChildAt(0);
                    final String firstText = firstTextView.getText().toString();


                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
                    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                                case R.id.menu1:
                                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, firstText);
                                    tl.removeView(v);

                                    return true;

                                default:
                                    return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });


                    popup.show();
                    return true;
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Из примера по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/373103/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%B2-android), в вашем случае можно как-то так написать:

```
tableRowView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
{    
    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View v)
    {
        //по этому ID вы можете в обработчике нажатия на меню узнать какой элемент в таблице вы нажали.
        final int idOfPressedView = v.getId();

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
        {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
            {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "idOfPressedView: "+idOfPressedView);
                TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
                TableRow row1 = (TableRow)tl.findViewById(idOfPressedView);

                TextView firstTextView = (TextView) row1.getChildAt(0);
                String firstText = firstTextView.getText().toString();

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, firstText);
                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.mark_as_read:
                    //действие
                    return true;
                    case R.id.share_link:
                   //действие
                    return true;
                    case R.id.show_comments:
                    //действие
                    return true;
                    default:
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
    }

});
```

И ещё нужен popup_menu.xml в папке /res/menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/mark_as_read"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:title="@string/mark_as_read"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/share_link"
    android:orderInCategory="50"
    android:title="@string/share_link"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/show_comments"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/show_comments"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Переменная` idOfPressedView` всегда показывает -1, но, в любом случае, спасибо Вам за потраченное время на ответы. Решение вопроса, я выложил выше.

Comment: @DenisMolodec, скорее всего это решается проставлением `id` при создании `tableRowView`)